# Select all links in a DIV except of an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an id. This div contain several links except one with a specified id. I have the following selector:

```
$("#smiley-box a").click(...
```

Now I need the same selector but it must be **NOT** applied to the link of the id `moreSmilies`

I tried this faulty code, which causes halting execution of the original code:

```
$("#smiley-box a :not(#moreSmilies)").click(function(e){
        //smiley = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        //$("#message").insertAtCursor(" "+smiley+" ")
        e.preventDefault();     
      })
    });
```

An example of the HTML I have:

```
<div id="smiley-box">
  <a href="#">someImage</a>
  <a href="#">someImage</a>
  <a href="#">someImage</a>

     <a id="moreSmilies" href="#">Another Task</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the space in `a :not(#moreSmilies)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#smiley-box a:not(#moreSmilies)")
```

remove space gap after `a`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space after `a` because you are targeting that element with the not selector.

`$("#smiley-box a :not(#moreSmilies)")`

should be

`$("#smiley-box a:not(#moreSmilies)")`